# How to read out revision of installed PHP extensions or other values exposed by phpinfo()

Tags: php, php-extension

My problem is relative simple, but I'm not getting much luck with searches for it, broad or narrow. On phpinfo I can find the following text for the posix extension:

```
posix

Revision    $Revision: 300764 $
```

The portion "$Revision: 300764 $" is what I'm after. Similar for extensions like SimpleXML, sysvmsg and other extensions where I would like to read out more details. For example in the openssl section, I'd like the value of "OpenSSL Library Version".

Is there any way to get values like these inside PHP, without doing the tango with output buffer, then parse the phpinfo output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `phpversion` with a supplied extension name:

```
<?php
$e=get_loaded_extensions();

foreach ($e as $ext)
{
        echo $ext.' : '.phpversion($ext)."\n";
}

$> php -f t.php
Core : 5.3.14
date : 5.3.14
ereg : 
libxml : 
openssl : 
pcre : 
sqlite3 : 0.7-dev
ctype : 
curl : 
dom : 20031129
fileinfo : 1.0.5-dev
filter : 0.11.0
ftp : 
gd : 
gettext : 
hash : 1.0
iconv : 
json : 1.2.1
ldap : 
mbstring : 
mcrypt : 
SPL : 0.2
session : 
standard : 5.3.14
mysqlnd : mysqlnd 5.0.8-dev - 20102224 - $Id: 65fe78e70ce53d27a6cd578597722950e490b0d0 $
PDO : 1.0.4dev
pdo_mysql : 1.0.2
pdo_sqlite : 1.0.1
Phar : 2.0.1
posix : 
Reflection : $Id: 522fef1e5100f848a5e2059d98b3a880a3143e9a $
mysqli : 0.1
SimpleXML : 0.1
SQLite : 2.0-dev
mysql : 1.0
tidy : 2.0
tokenizer : 0.1
xml : 
xmlreader : 0.1
xmlwriter : 0.1
xdebug : 2.2.0
```

Comment: Thank you for your example, but it clearly demonstrates what I'm missing. The info from posix and openssl you get with this are both empty. I'm trying to get this extended info in a consistent way and can't find one short of parsing the output from phpinfo() or using the reflection class to get that html bit with this info and parse it from there. Neither one is satisfying.